# purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x1d57ba00

Tags: iphone, objective-c

What's going on here? This is the first time I've ever seen this in the log.

I'm connected to NTP servers.

Building on iPhone running iOS 6.0 with latest version of XCode.

Should I ignore this? It doesn't seem to be doing anything else to my app...

Comment: Here is Apple Q&A about the message. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1774/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012992

Answer (score 7):

IMPORTANT: You will get this message only when you run the App on a real device (iPhone 4 with iOS 6.0.1). This device uses a 3G-connection, not a WIFI-connection.

I do not get this message when I run the App on the simulator or when i run the application on device with Wifi.

Comment: Same over here...After message is displayed on Console App gets Freezed for short time. How to deal with this?